# How to extend the datastore example with an image upload to blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I spent a few days researching this and I think it's a general enough question to ask here so that it would benefit other beginners.
I have few ideas how to solve it and would like guidance of a more experienced person.

the example code in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/usingdatastore
creates a template and redirects to "/sign" when the submit button is pressed. At "/sign", the form values are loaded into datastore and the client is redirected to "/"

the example code in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/
creates a template and from my understanding when the submit button is pressed, the form values are loaded into blobstore and the client is redirected to "/upload"

so from my understanding, in blobstore, the writing is before redirecting to "/upload", and in datastore, the writing is after redirecting to "/sign"

So the question is how do I split writing an image to blobstore and writing info about the image to datastore when pressing submit?

The simplest solution that I thought of is on "submit" to use blobstore method and write everything to blobstore then get data with r.FromValue("info") and put it into datastore.
the disadvantage is that I have a duplicate of "info" in both datastore and blobstore.

The other solution would be to "submit" the form with datastore method and then manually put the image to blobstore. The way I found to do it, which might not be optimal, is to convert the image to []byte ([Golang Converting image.Image to []byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945486/golang-converting-image-image-to-byte)) the us blobstore.Create and writer.write([]byte)
The disadvantage of this method is that image might be too big to be redirected to "/sign". This comment is my inexperienced intuition and i might be wrong.

I highly appreciate your help

Comment: I got some help from @LouFranco via AirPair with this and I allowed the solution to be public.  I needed to upload the image via Google Endpoint to the Blobstore from an iPhone app.  It requires several Endpoint calls.  I believe the first obtains a blobstore key and then the iPhone's Objective-C code makes multiple calls to post the data in chunks with a protocol called multi-part I think.  I'm not sure if it's relevant to you but I can post more detail if so.