# In Go what do I return to get a handle on this png image so I can pass it to other functions?

Tags: go, interface

The first function writes the image directly to local.

The second is something that I'm aiming for; to get a return value that I can pass on to either a local or cloud storage writer.

The save to Google Cloud Storage function needs an io.Reader as it uses io.Copy.

```
func makeCatImage() {
    myImg := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 12, 6))
    out, _ := os.Create("cat.png")
        
    _ = png.Encode(out, myImg)
        
        _ = out.Close()
    }


func getCatImage() someReturnValue {
    myImg := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 12, 6))

    // TODO ... 

    _ = png.Encode(out, myImg)
    return out
    }
```

Comment: Your example of something that works doesn't compile I think (`out := bufio.NewWriter(out)` doesn't look right), and you return an io.Writer, but it looks like this is a bufio.Writer that's already been used and closed, so I can't imagine this is helpful. Can you back up and say exactly what it is you want to do? You've phrased it in terms of a program "I want a return value that I can pass on..." but can you be more descriptive in what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/22945486/5728991 answer your question?

Comment: @PaulHankin Sorry about that, I need to get some sleep. I've removed my so called working code.

Comment: Thanks greatly @CeriseLimón. I think that's what I need to return: a *bytes.Buffer. Would you like to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

who create who destory

```
func makeCatImageHttp(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    //ResponseWriter Close by net/http, you have not create it, need not close it 
    getCatImage(w)
}

func makeCatImageLocal() {
    //Local file must Close you have create it, so close it
    out, _ := os.Create("cat.png")
    defer out.Close()
    getCatImage(out)
}

func getCatImage(w io.Writer) {
    myImg := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 12, 6))
    _ = png.Encode(w, myImg)
}
```